# what are the automatic changes in css dark-mode?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a site which already is overall dark (https://spacetrace.org), but since the new dark mode in Firefox exists, if it is selected, some colours and image transparencies are then changed somehow, which breaks  the overall style.

I couldn't find an official document that explains the automatic changes.

How do I find out what was changed and revert those unexpected changes?

Note: I would like to enhance the site so it does what the user wants, and serve a working dark version using media query:

```
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  /*  css */
}
```

But I cannot find the CSS options that were changed, so I can adapt them

Comment: `html,body{ width:100vw; height:100vh; background:#fff; }` if you want a white background.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are talking about this.

http://kb.mozillazine.org/index.php?title=UserChrome.css&printable=yes#Editing;
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-color-scheme;

All you need is to add userChrome.css file with some code like this:

```
:root:not(:-moz-lwtheme) {
  background-color: #e3e4e6 !important;
  color: #18191a !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to revert the changes locally but on the server, I am the admin of the site.